# Using different directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, web

I'm having a bit of trouble doing the following,

URL `site.com/admin`  should display the contents form the folder `site.com/core/admin`

I tried a few times times but my Apache server gives me *internal server error*.

Comment: If that's all you want, you're better of with an [`Alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html), if you're allowed to alter vhost settings.

Comment: I will look at it now. Never knew this was possible

Comment: Currently stuck with a shared hosting. I can not access the configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^core/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/$1 [L]
```

If you only want "admin", then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin$ /core/admin [L]
```

Comment: Using this I'm also redirected to site.com/core/admin. the site.com/admin has to be something like a virtual folder

Comment: That rule is doing no redirecting. Unless admin is a folder (in which case, apache will automatically redirect all requests to folders without trailing slashes to the same URL *with* the trailing slash).

Comment: Apache will always redirect folders missing trailing slashes, if it doesn't anyone can look at all the contents of your folders even if you have an index file